# After response list was not added to listview in android

Tags: android, listview

Hi in the below code I am getting the below response from the server.After getting the response I am taking name and then adding to the listview.

But,In the below listview is not displaying .Empty Listview is displaying.I am able to print the separably id and name.
Form that name want to add to list.

Can any one help me after response want to add to the listview.

Response:

```
[{"ID":"2","Name":"Building 1"},{"ID":"3","Name":"Building 2"},{"ID":"4","Name":"Building 3"},{"ID":"36","Name":"Building 4"}]
```

Refresh.java:

```
private void doTheAutoRefresh() {
        handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // Write code for your refresh logic

                progressDialog = new ProgressDialog (getActivity ());
                progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
                progressDialog.setMessage("Communicating...");
                progressDialog.setCanceledOnTouchOutside(false);
                progressDialog.setCancelable(false);
                progressDialog.show();
                OkHttpClient client = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                        .connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .writeTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .readTimeout(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                        .build();

                Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                        .baseUrl(API.URL_BASE)
                        .addConverterFactory(ScalarsConverterFactory.create())
                        .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                        .client (client)
                        .build();
                API service = retrofit.create (API.class);
                Call<List<GetBuildingList>> userCall = service.getbuildinglist ();
                userCall.enqueue(new Callback<List<GetBuildingList>> () {

                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(Call <List<GetBuildingList>> call, Response <List<GetBuildingList>> response) {

                        Log.d("Call request", call.request().toString());
                        Log.d("Call request header", call.request().headers().toString());

                        Log.d("Response raw header", response.headers().toString());
                        Log.d("Response raw", String.valueOf(response.raw().body()));
                        Log.d("Response code", String.valueOf(response.code()));

                        if(response.isSuccessful()) {
                            progressDialog.dismiss ( );
                            Log.d ("Response body", new Gson ( ).toJson (response.body ( )));
                            //JSONArray jsonArray=new JSONArray ();
                            String Status = new Gson ( ).toJson (response.body ( ));


                                JSONArray jsonArray = null;
                                 List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
                                 JSONObject jsonObject=null;
                                try {
                                    jsonArray = new JSONArray (Status);
                                    jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject (0);
                                    for (int i=0;i<=jsonObject.length ();i++){
                                        String id=jsonObject.getString ("ID");
                                        String name=jsonObject.getString ("Name");

                                        arrayList = new ArrayList <String> ( );
                                        adapter = new ArrayAdapter <String> (getActivity ( ), R.layout.building_listview_item, arrayList);
                                        MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter (arrayList, this);
                                        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                                        arrayList.add (name);
                                        System.out.println (arrayList.add (name));
                                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged ();
                                    }


                                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                                    e.printStackTrace ( );

                            }

                        }

                        else  {
                            progressDialog.dismiss ();
                            Log.d("Response errorBody", String.valueOf(response.errorBody()));
                        }

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(Call<List<GetBuildingList>> call, Throwable t) {
                       // lv.setAdapter (adapter);
                        System.out.println("onFailure");
                        System.out.println(t.fillInStackTrace());
                        progressDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(getActivity (), "Some error occurred -> ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();;
                        // progressDialog.dismiss();



                    }

                });
            }


        }, 5000);
        return ;
    }
```

Comment: Did you just create `Adapter` inside loop ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is here with the loop

```
for (int i=0;i<=jsonObject.length ();i++){
                                        String id=jsonObject.getString ("ID");
                                        String name=jsonObject.getString ("Name");

                                        arrayList = new ArrayList <String> ( );
                                        adapter = new ArrayAdapter <String> (getActivity ( ), R.layout.building_listview_item, arrayList);
                                        MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter (arrayList, this);
                                        lv.setAdapter(adapter);
                                        arrayList.add (name);
                                        System.out.println (arrayList.add (name));
                                        adapter.notifyDataSetChanged ();
                                    }
```

Just replace it and its working fine

```
arrayList = new ArrayList <String> ( );
     for (int i=0;i<=jsonObject.length ();i++){
         String id=jsonObject.getString ("ID");
         String name=jsonObject.getString ("Name");
          arrayList.add (name);
  }

adapter = new ArrayAdapter <String> (getActivity ( ), 
             R.layout.building_listview_item, arrayList);
MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter (arrayList, this);
 lv.setAdapter(adapter);
```

One more thing why you are creating two instance of same variable

**adapter = new ArrayAdapter...**

**adapter = new MyCustomAdapter (arrayList, this);**

I will suggest you to use different variable names.

Comment: So whats  the issue now?

Comment: After clicking the button.I am adding to listview

Comment: System.out.println (name); for this Building 1 was printing in logcat

Comment: Could you print the array-list after loop it will show all the values

Comment: it is printing [] arraylist

Comment: Collection name = Collections.singleton (jsonObject.getString ("Name"));
                                       // System.out.println (arrayList.addAll (name));
                                        Log.d ("name", String.valueOf (arrayList.add (name)));
o/p:System.out: [[Building 1], [Building 1], [Building 1]]

Comment: Help me out from this issue

Answer (score 0):

```
    try {
                                jsonArray = new JSONArray (Status);
                                jsonObject=jsonArray.getJSONObject (0);
                                for (int i=0;i<=jsonObject.length ();i++){
                                    String id=jsonObject.getString ("ID");
                                    String name=jsonObject.getString ("Name");


                                 arrayList.add(name);
                  //   arrayList = new ArrayList <String> ( ); //this in the beginning not in the for loop 
                                System.out.println (arrayList.add (name));
                                }

                                    adapter = new ArrayAdapter <String> (getActivity ( ), R.layout.building_listview_item, arrayList);
                                    MyCustomAdapter adapter = new MyCustomAdapter (arrayList, this);
                                    lv.setAdapter(adapter);


                                    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged ();
```